# C# Passing variable between two event handlers

Tags: c#

I have question about passing a variable from one event handler to another. To be specific, here is my code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string loggedIn = File.ReadLines("Data.txt").Last();

    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        writingToTxtFile();
    }
```

I would like to pass variable "loggedIn" (or its value) to method "Form1_FormClosing" (to be specific to "writingToTxtFile" function). The only solution I thought of was to use global variables. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: C# doesn't even have global variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
private string _loggedIn;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _loggedIn = File.ReadLines("Data.txt").Last();
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    //do something with _loggedIn
    writingToTxtFile();
}
```

Comment: Looks like i got the concept of global variables in C# wrong, because I would have thought that this IS global variable. I am new to C# and started coding without reading some manuals and such, so I am learning lot of things while I am programming (or at least trying to). However, thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to understand the concept of what a global variable is, to understand why that is not global variable and why they're not in C#. Try looking up "scope" in C#. In this case You just need a private field since both of your functions are instance methods in the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Store in private String out of function but in class.

Answer (score -1):

you can create a page property and it will be populated through the page events and methods.
and you can use it in any method.

by that you changed the scope for the variable to all the page scope.